# Android Studio : Unable to delete original file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I'm  very new to android and I just recently cloned an Android project.

When Android Studios performs the indexing once opening the project, i get this error all the time.

this is the error I get from Android Studio.

```
Error:(89, 0) Failed to delete original file 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download8065263342645015068bin' 
after copy to 'C:\Users\myname\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.build\gradle\1.5.0\1c3d2b23212349ffbe6479fcb04732c5cddaf98b\gradle-1.5.0.pom'
<a href="openFile:D:\myname\mobile-myapp-tester\platforms\android\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Comment: Just try to clean project and then build the project

Comment: I tried cleaning it, but I get the same error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the next step to "Refresh" your IDE (android studio)

[Choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause is the Anti-virus. It may block Gradle or Java

Comment: This is correct answer. When I turn off my anti-virus error disappeared.Thanks yzn!!!

Comment: This was the case with me, disabling anti virus did the trick. Probably need to change the settings in anti virus.

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reasons for this error but are usually linked to `Rights`. I solved this by following these 2 different steps at different times.

- Run Android Studio as `Administrator`
- Check if the your project folder is `read-only` ? If yes, remove the `read-only` attribute from Folder Properties.

Answer (score 1):

If Invalidate Caches/Restart doesn't work, change your GRADLE BUILD TOOL to any lower Version, or different Version untill it works

For me I got the error for Gragle 2.2.3, but fixed when I changed to 2.1.3, you can try with different newer versions from here [Gradle Build Tools](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve my issue by disabling the Instant Run feature of android studio.